# 2 comparator classes in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I'm in my second computer programming class ever and have been asked to write a program that implements 2 comparator classes. Here's my code below but I can't figure out why Collections.sort(newStudent, new sortByName()); and Collections.sort(newStudent, new sortByRollNo()); elicits an error. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class StudentObjects {
    int rollno;
    String name;
    String address;

public StudentObjects(int rollno, String name, String address) { //constructor
    this.rollno = rollno;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.rollno + " " + this.name + " " + this.address; //to print in main
}

class sortByName implements Comparator<StudentObjects> {
    public int compare(StudentObjects a, StudentObjects b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
}

class sortByRollNo implements Comparator<StudentObjects> {
    public int compare(StudentObjects a, StudentObjects b) {
        return a.rollno - b.rollno;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
    ArrayList<StudentObjects> newStudent = new ArrayList<StudentObjects>();
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(342, "Harry Potter", "4 Privet Drive"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(555, "Hermione Granger", "67 Hampstead Garden"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(788, "Ron Weasley", "5 Ottery St Catchpole"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(542, "Albus Dumbledore", "88 Godric's Hollow"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(972, "Sirius Black", "12 Grimmauld Place"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(125, "Remus Lupin", "12 Grimmauld Place"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(783, "Neville Longbottom", "Hogwarts Castle"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(168, "Luna Lovegood", "24 Ottery St Catchpole"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(224, "Severus Snape", "12 Spinner's End"));
        newStudent.add(new StudentObjects(991, "Minerva McGonagall", "Hogwarts Castle"));

        Collections.sort(newStudent, new sortByName());
            System.out.println("Students sorted by name: ");
            for (i=0; i<newStudent.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(newStudent.get(i));
            }

        System.out.println("");

        Collections.sort(newStudent, new sortByRollNo());
            System.out.println("Students sorted by roll number: ");
            for (i=0; i<newStudent.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(newStudent.get(i));
            }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you please post it.

Comment: I didn't get an error/exception.

Comment: Always include the error in the question. We don't like guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these two classes outside your main class "Student Objects" in the same file or in different files or make them inner classes.

```
class sortByName implements Comparator<StudentObjects> {
    public int compare(StudentObjects a, StudentObjects b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
}

class sortByRollNo implements Comparator<StudentObjects> {
    public int compare(StudentObjects a, StudentObjects b) {
        return a.rollno - b.rollno;
    }
}
```

Comment: OH! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're creating a class within a class, which is fine, but if you're going to reference the [inner class](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inner_classes.asp) from a static context that class also needs to be defined as static.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!